# Error al ejecutar sentencia en SQL Server 2008

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Necesito ejecutar esta sentencia de MYSQL en SQLServer

```
CREATE TABLE venta (
  idVenta INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
  Fecha DATE NOT NULL, 
  Cliente_Cedula INTEGER NOT NULL,
  producto_idProducto INTEGER NOT NULL,
  empleado_Cedula INTEGER NOT NULL,
  cantidad INTEGER NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY ([Cliente_Cedula])
    REFERENCES cliente ([Cedula])
    FOREIGN KEY ([empleado_Cedula])
    REFERENCES empleado ([Cedula])
    FOREIGN KEY ([producto_idProducto])
    REFERENCES producto ([idProducto])
  );
```

Me sale el siguiente mensaje de error

```
Sintaxis incorrecta cerca de la palabra clave 'FOREIGN'.
```

¿Alguien por acá sería tan amable de decirme que estoy haciendo mal en la sentencia?

Comment: Esa estructura corresponde a MySQL, debes realizar algo muy similar pero para MSSQL Server ;)

Comment: http://www.sqlines.com/online

Comment: quita esos acentos franceses `\`` y pon apostrofes `'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debe funcionar en SQL Server:

```
CREATE TABLE venta (
  idVenta INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
  Fecha DATE NOT NULL, 
  Cliente_Cedula INTEGER NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES cliente ([Cedula]),
  producto_idProducto INTEGER NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES producto ([idProducto]),
  empleado_Cedula INTEGER NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES empleado ([Cedula]),
  cantidad INTEGER NOT NULL
  );
```